# mojolicious morbo server is caching by default?

Tags: perl, mojolicious, morbo

I generated a full app from the command console:

```
 mojo generate app MyApp
```

After that i started the dev server:

```
morbo myapp
```

I changed some code, even changed the name of the default controller, but i can not see any changes in the browser, only if i restart the morbo server works.
This is reallly annoying for developing. 
How to get rid of this caching behaviour?

UPDATE: i noticed if i use hypnotoad instead morbo, works and updates changes properly, so the problem is morbo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never had this problem before but there is watch().

http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/Server/Morbo#watch

Maybe if you explicitly tell the server where to look for
changed files it will work.  Or, perhaps that can help you 
find where the problem is.

Comment: thanks, the watch param do the trick. adding -w /route/towatch when the server starts from console

Comment: Tried all the recommendations in this thread without success.  Adding -w /route/towatch worked for me but I still need to hit F5 (refresh) a couple of times in the browser for the changes to take effect. Would love to have this sorted completely.

Answer (score 3):

On an aditional note, if you want to have live updates directly using morbo+fullapp you should cd to the app's folder then run

```
$ morbo script/myapp
```

It would then work properly.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted, not chdir:ing into the app's folder seems to cause issues such as cached pages and recompilation being flakey